# Three months on new job but just offered new one, do I tell new employer about it or do I leave it out?

Tags: hiring-process

I am in need of advice in my situation. I left my job after being there for two years, and started a new job three months ago. I've just gotten a new job offer that is much better.

I would love to know if I should tell the new company about this three month job, or if I can leave it out and just tell them about previous employer and my two year tenure there, please help me here.

I am worried about so many question from HR why and how, so want to avoid that but I don't want to lie and be caught if HR can find out about my shorter stint.

Thank you all

Comment: Is this for a resume, your work history of all past jobs in an application or something else? Depending on the context, various answers may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the truth to whom it may concern. The new prospective employer made a much more attractive offer and presumably is offering professional development opportunities that your current employer is in no position to match.

Don't say that your current employer is not a good fit if that's not the truth. You don't want to put down a good employer and you want to keep excellent relations with them, as you go on to (much) better things.

I wouldn't be shy about telling Google that I'dump my current employer for them in a nanosecond. Sometimes, you just have to jump at the chance knowing that there will be some collateral damage.